# call parameter value jenkins from shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to be able to call the parameters value from the shell and use it in my shell script. My priority is to not use If for every value selected in the params, but rather it  choose the active choice. Is it possible as am having issue with this error?

**line 4: ${params.prime_server}: bad substitution**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy
    
        properties([
        parameters([
    
                   choice(
           name: 'prime_server',
                   choices: ['','choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3','choice4'],
            description: 'Name choice'
            ),
             choice(
           name: 'old_server',
                   choices: ['','choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3','choice4'],
            description: 'Name choice'
            )
        ])
    ]) 
    
    stage('stage1') {
      environment{
       
        }
        node("master") {
    
         sh '''
          
    echo -e "-------------------------------Calling the params value into shell----------------------------"
    echo  "${params.prime_server}"
    echo  "${params.old_server}"
    oldserver="${params.old_server}"
    primeserver="${params.prime_server}"
    echo  "${oldserver}"
    echo  "${primeserver}"
    
  sed -i -e "0,/${oldserver}/ s/${oldserver}/${primeserver}/g" test.xml
  
    
    '''.stripIndent()
      
        
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to call this param value and assign it to variables in shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using double quotes if you want Groovy to do string interpolation. So change your shell block like below.

```
sh """
          
    echo -e "-------------------------------Calling the params value into shell----------------------------"
    echo  "${params.prime_server}"
    echo  "${params.old_server}"
    oldserver="${params.old_server}"
    primeserver="${params.prime_server}"
    echo  "\${oldserver}"
    echo  "\${primeserver}"
    sed -i -e "0,/${oldserver}/ s/${oldserver}/${primeserver}/g" test.xml
    
    """.stripIndent()
```

Comment: I have used that before, it is failing at the oldserver variables with this error :  No such property: oldserver for class: WorkflowScript

Comment: You simply don't need to interpolate the variable `oldserver` since it's defined in the `sh` scope. Hence escape the $ character so it will not be considered as a variable. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shell block with single quotes does not take variables into consideration, so double quotes must be used.
Example:

```
sh """
    <your code>
"""
```

Comment: Thanks. I used it before but is failing at old server variable No such property: oldserver for class: WorkflowScript